# "Web Service method name is not valid" when URL contains additional slashes after method name

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

I have a simple ASP WebService with a WebMethod, i.e.:

```
public class MyService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in MyMethod, the breakpoint is hit when I point my browser to:
http://example.com/MyService.asmx/MyMethod

But I get "Web Service method name is not valid" error (and breakpoint not hit) if I go to:
http://example.com/MyService.asmx/MyMethod/2

How can I get MyMethod to be called when there are additional forward slashes (and parameters) after the method name in the URL?

Comment: I doubt WebMethod supports a slash. You'll just have to find another way to pass your parameters. Probably the better question though: why are you creating a new WebMethod in 2021?

Comment: I'm working in an existing project and trying to repair some functionality that apparently used to work. The URL with slashes comes from 3rd party code and follows a spec, so changing it isn't an option. There are WebServices and WebMethods all over this code though, if I want to modernize things what should I be using instead?

Comment: Probably the ultimate thing to do would be running on ASP.NET Core, probably using API controllers or perhaps even gRPC. Of course, that's a big rewrite, so to take baby steps you could integrate ASP.NET Web API into your .NET Framework project and slowly port functionality from the WebMethods into Web API controllers. Once all or most of that is ported, it would be a lot simpler to go to .NET Core and ASP.NET Core.

Comment: If this "used to work", how did it work before? What changed about it? Presumably if this was working before with the slashes, something must have been in place to make those work. Is your project properly source controlled? Is there any URL rewriting logic going on anywhere?

Comment: That's the real kicker, I can't figure out what changed! The code is under source control and this part hasn't been edited in quite a while, and I've personally seen the functionality work (as an end-user of the site) in the past. I'm not aware of any URL rewriting logic and definitely not any recent changes to such logic if it exists (small team). Perhaps it's worth looking into introducing the first Web API controller into the project...

Comment: do you have friendly URL's turned on? As such, then the "/" should work for parameters. Also during testing? Do a ctrl-f5 to re-load the browser cache - you lose a day easy due to URL and browser caching during testing -

Comment: Are your configuration files source controlled? Is it possible there was rewrite logic or other configuration there that enabled the slashes, and these got wiped out? Or is there any network appliance between client and web server that can rewrite the routes?

Comment: I just tried adding and configuring the NuGet for FriendlyUrls, but no change to the results. Config files are also under source control and have not changed in any significant way recently.